# filter object by key and its items

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I have an object that I would like to filter it's keys..

Im trying to filter the object by an ID, like so:

```
let myKeys = Object.keys(data).filter(function(key) {
        //console.log(data[key]);
        if(parseInt(key) === parseInt(vm.system_id)) {
            return data[key];
        }
    });

    console.log(myKeys);
```

This works, partialy - im getting the key, however, im not getting all the data/items under this item im filtering out

The object im filtering is one similar to this one:

```
{
"646": [{
        "id": 52144,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-17T14:10:23Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 210,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "remedy": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-17T14:10:09Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "CG-MX19D7K5C1",
        "system_id": 646,
        "system_device_id": 458,
        "stream": "cu351.alarm_code"
    }
],
"693": [{
        "id": 51675,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-16T13:59:55Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 215,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "remedy": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-16T13:59:57Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Demo 07122016",
        "system_id": 693,
        "system_device_id": 371,
        "stream": "cu351.alarm_code"
    }, {
        "id": 51677,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-16T13:59:57Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 214,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "remedy": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-16T13:59:59Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Demo 07122016",
        "system_id": 693,
        "system_device_id": 371,
        "stream": "cu351.alarm_code"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is expecting a boolean value as return value, you might use this

```
let myKeys = Object.keys(data).filter(key => key == vm.system_id);
```

for getting the keys and then render a new object with the given keys.

To get all items in a single array, you could collect them with

```
let result = myKeys.reduce((r, k) => r.concat(data[k]), []);
```

Comment: Not quite, this still just returns an array with the key ['693'] - But not giving me all the data under this item

Comment: right, you need another loop please add an example and what you expect.